# Linear w.r.t. any measure

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, terminology

Let $X$ be a Banach space endowed with a Borel $\sigma$-algebra. How do we call a real-valued Borel function $f$ that satisfies for any Borel probability measure $\mu$ the following formula
$$
  \int_X f(x)\mu(dx) = f\left(\int_Xx \mu(dx)\right).
$$
If we focus only on discrete measures $\mu$ then $f$ is just any linear function, however I wonder whether there is a special term for $f$ that satisfies such linearity condition for all measures.

Comment: Do you have an example of a continuous linear functional that does not have this property?

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier. [this answer of yours](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/863798/5887), I believe.

Comment: I don't see it. The answer does involve a normed space and a functional on it, but what is $\mu$ on this normed space (of measures)?

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier. Suppose $X = \mathcal P(\Omega)$, and consider the functional $\phi(\mu)$ you've constructed. In case it would satisfy the property above, we could define $g(\omega) := \phi(\delta_\omega)$ and we would obtain
$$
  \phi(\mu) = \phi\left(\int_\Omega\delta_\omega\mu(d\omega)\right) = \phi\left(\int_{\mathcal P(\Omega)}x (\delta_*\mu)(dx)\right)
$$
$$
 = \int_{\mathcal P(\Omega)}\phi(x)(\delta_*\mu)(dx) = \int_\Omega g(\omega)\mu(d\omega)
$$
if I am not mistaken: here $\delta_*\mu$ is the pushforward of $\mu$ along $\delta:\omega\mapsto\delta_\omega$.

Comment: The function $\omega \mapsto \phi(\delta_\omega)$ is the limit of Rademacher functions along a non-principal ultrafilter, and such a thing [is not measurable](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/275440/), even in the Lebesgue sense.

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier. Now I'm confused: $\omega\mapsto \delta_\omega$ is measurable w.r.t. the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathcal P(\Omega)$ endowed with the topology of weak convergence. Since $\phi:\mathcal P(\Omega)\to \Bbb R$ from your example is Lipschitz continuous in TV, shall not it be continuous in weak convergence and thus Borel as well?

Comment: My fault for confusing you in the other thread. Weak topology is weaker than TV, and therefore continuity with respect to weak topology is a *stronger* condition than continuity with respect to TV. Hence my other answer is wrong.

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier.: well, I guess if one can show that the strong form of linearity in this question always holds for linear operators on measures, that automatically implies the representation in the other thread.

Comment: And that would follow from finite linear combinations of point masses being weakly dense? (This is before coffee, so I'm not sure).

Comment: This looks like a fundamental propertie of the Bochner integral : if $T$ is a continuous linear operator and $f$ integrable then $\int Tf d \mu = T\int fd\mu$. Also like meta stated the set of average of weighted dirac measures is dense in the set of Borel measures (in the weak star sense), this probably extends to the Bochner inegral too.